# Passing metadata between functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created an API with Node.js, and I don't want the API to change nor do I want to add extra parameters to a function. However, the internal code in the library needs to now send some metadata between an internal API method and an external facing method.

Is there a way to pass (meta) data between functions somehow in JS that does not involve parameters/arguments?

TL;DR, it would be really useful to pass metadata between functions for the purposes of JS APIs, that should not change signatures.

(One trick is if the function is created everytime it is called, you can assign data onto the function object itself, but that is not true in this case (function is not being created everytime it is called).)

The trick I am currently using - and it is *not* a good one - there is an options {} object being used in the API. I am passing a hidden property in that objects object "__preParsed". The user will use that objects object as they normally would, behind the scenes I use it for some bookkeeping stuff that they don't need to know about.

Ok here is the code:

//public API

```
   beforeEach.cb = function (desc, opts, fn) {
        const _args = pragmatik.parse(arguments, rules.hookSignature);
        _args[ 1 ].cb = true;
        return beforeEach.apply(ctx, _args);
   };


   beforeEach = function (desc, opts, aBeforeEach) {

        handleSetupComplete(zuite);

        const _args = pragmatik.parse(arguments, rules.hookSignature);

        const obj = {        //have to do this until destructuring works
          desc: _args[ 0 ],
          opts: _args[ 1 ],
          fn: _args[ 2 ]
        };

        handleBadOptionsForEachHook(obj.opts, zuite);

        return 'there is more code but I omitted it';
    };
```

as you can see the first method calls the second, or the second can be called directly, both are public APIs.

We need to parse the arguments in both calls, but as an optimization, we shouldn't have to parse them a second time if the second method was called by the first instead of directly.

The solution I will use for the moment is:

```
       beforeEach.cb = function (desc, opts, fn) {
            const _args = pragmatik.parse(arguments, rules.hookSignature);
            _args[ 1 ].cb = true;
            _args[ 1 ].__preParsed = true;
            return beforeEach.apply(ctx, _args);
       };
```

the opts options object is public, but the user won't know about the __preParsed property. The internal API will.

The problem with this is that the user can call the public API directly without an options object, and since the signature is very much varargs, then I really don't know until I have parsed it with my parse engine, which arg if any is the objects object!

Answer (score 2):

You could abuse the `this` object to carry non-argument metadata in as follows by invoking your function using `Function.prototype.call`:

```
function inner (arg1, arg2) {
  console.log('inner called with', arg1, arg2)
  console.log('inner metadata', this._meta_count)
}

inner.call({_meta_count: 17}, 'ARG ONE', 'ARG TWO')
inner.call({_meta_count: 18}, 'ARG ONE B', 'ARG TWO B')
```

Comment: Really nice, as long as the function doesn't already use `this`

Comment: yeah unfortunately, already have a context, although I could just add hidden properties to that context, the problem is, I'd have to set and then unset the property, as this is a method on that context, and the property value is only relevant to the lifetime of the method call...It's better to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: I am going to just bring out the code so it's clear what's happening

Comment: TL;DR, it would be really useful to pass metadata between functions for the purposes of JS APIs, that should not change signatures. (next time you design a programming language :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a new  undocumented parameter to the end. JavaScript won't care and previous calls will still work, why is that a problem for you?

If you are checking parameter count and throwing errors, you could expect the hidden parameter to be an object with a magic property, if it's not, throw the error.

```
function go(a, b, c, _internal) {
  if (_internal && ! _internal.hasOwnProperty('_magic')) {
    throw new Error('invalid internal parameter passed');
  }
}
```

You can get a little more paranoid and store the magic property as a [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol), then the caller couldn't pass it by accident, they would have to be acting nefariously.

```js
function go(a, b, c, _internal) {
  if (_internal && !_internal.hasOwnProperty(go.internalParamProp)) {
    throw new Error('invalid internal parameter passed');
  }
  console.log("Internal param", _internal && _internal[go.internalParamProp])
}
// Symbol for the magic property name to avoid accidental passing of internal param
go.internalParamProp = Symbol('');

// Passing the internal param
// Uses JS syntax that is not yet supported in some browsers
// If it's a concern, use or var obj={}; obj[go.internalParamProp] = 45
go(1, 2, 3, {
  [go.internalParamProp]: 45
})

// Regular call
go(1, 2, 3)

// Invalid call
go(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Big problem because then my code might think that extra parameter is coming from the user, not from my lib, and then throw an error saying the user was using the lib wrong. What if the user passed in 4 vars instead of 3, and then I pick up the wrong var for the 4th? :) all sorts of potential problems as you can see.

Comment: I edited the original answer, my current solution depends on the API already having an options object passed between functions in the API. But this is not a general solution because not all APIs have an objects object being passed along, although in general it might work if you add an options obj to your APIs!

Comment: I think any answer will be a hack that's not 100%. Peter's answer is not fool proof. Both still allow the caller to pass internal data, but make it less likely. I prefer mine because it still works if your function relies on `this` and you can call it without `call` or `apply`